# caliburn micro: reuse existing commands

Tags: wpf, action, caliburn.micro, routed-commands

I have a simple wpf application with a Control (let's say a Button) that fires a Command (let's say ApplicationCommands.Copy). I want that same Control (the Button) to be context sensitive, that is, it performs the proper action (send the Copy command), according to the currently focused Control. So, if the focus is on a TextBox, the command is sent to the Textbox, while if another Control has the focus, then the command is sent to it.
Now, I have another Control, a ContentControl whose model is set in XAML through Caliburn Micro's View.Model="{Binding ...}" attribute.

I would like to maintain the "context sensitivity" of the button, that is, the copy command should be handled by the ContentControl's ViewModel.

An attempt was made to set a binding to the proper model's method in the model's view. This works fine, but on the other hand, the suggested way to handle similar situations with Caliburn Micro seems to be to avoid Commands, and to use Actions instead. Is it possible to implement a similar handling using only actions? What's the suggested way to integrate existing command with Caliburn Micro?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the default action is always tied to the control name

```
<Button x:Name="Copy" Content="Copy"/>
```

in viewmodel

```
public void Copy()
{
}
```

if you want the same button to do multiple function you can do it in the method itself

```
public void Copy()
{
   // check and get which control has focus

   // copy content to the control that has focus
}
```